# LiveAgent: the agent is online but no chat request appears

Tags: rest-api, liveagent, chat

We want to use the liveagent feature in salesforce via rest API.
We created everything that needed for it - deployment, chat button, console app and so..

From the console - chat supervisor I can see the agent marked as available, but no request appears in the chat window after sending a `ChasitorInit` request, although we get 200 OK in response.

**URL**: https://our-endpoint.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChasitorInit

**BODY**: {"organizationId":"XXXX", "deploymentId":"XXXX", "buttonId":"XXXX", "sessionId":"56XXXXXX00279", "userAgent":"Lynx/2.8.8", "language":"en-US", "screenResolution":"1900x1080", "prechatDetails":[], "prechatEntities":[], "receiveQueueUpdates":true, "isPost":true}

**RESPONSE**: {"statusCode":200,"body":"OK"}

can someone help?
[image]

Comment: this guy faced a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332875/salesforce-live-agent-rest-api-not-working-when-using-postman

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the same - I'm sending the correct buttonId in the request

Comment: @user2503775 does this help https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384130&type=1 ?

Comment: no, it doesn't...

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue. Do you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: There is no error in the browser console (of the agent)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I changed chat button id digit from 18 to 15.